Spark Streaming MinIO Write Issue
I have docker containers for spark-iceberg, rest catalog and minio. When I am trying to write data to iceberg tables, I am getting the following error
Code
query = windowed_df.writeStream \
        .outputMode("complete") \
        .format("iceberg") \
        .option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/spark/checkpoints/crypto_metrics5") \
        .toTable("db.crypto_metrics5")

pyspark.errors.exceptions.captured.StreamingQueryException: [STREAM_FAILED] Query [id = 303e6f73-74ef-4b7c-ba93-14683e05f1ec, runId = 83365d1e-1d66-4940-80f6-52fe56fb9d5b] terminated with exception: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 1.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 8) (2d919ed2adc9 executor driver): software.amazon.awssdk.services.s3.model.S3Exception: The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint. (Service: S3, Status Code: 301, Request ID: V0HP2CWK6JA6EZEK, Extended Request ID: aWpwZSAKhAxK+2fJdcsqnQoLXYjMGwNU8rJhMppyY/KFAH8JHPsDCWBiRrxm+/bH9pZ9RiM2Juc=)

Spark submit command
spark-submit \
    --packages org.apache.iceberg:iceberg-spark-runtime-3.5_2.12:1.7.1,org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.5.4 \
    --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest.type=rest \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest.uri=http://rest:8181 \
    --conf spark.sql.catalog.rest=org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog \
    --conf spark.sql.defaultCatalog=rest \
    test.py

I can see the metadata files in the minio path. What am I possibly be doing wrong?

there's an extended request id in the error message -so it came from AWS not minio. check your configuration
